# Navigation Drawe

Tags: java, android

recién estoy empezando en Android Studio, acabé de crear un Navigation Drawer, pero a la hora de mostrar la interfaz gráfica, me muestra lo siguiente

[image: Navigation Drawer en Android Studio]

No se a qué se deba este comportamiento, ya he intentado varias cosas pero no logro solucionarlo.